# I think I found a bug in torch.nn.functional.conv2d()

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

conv2d() returns an error saying that output_padding is wrong, yet conv2d() doesn't have an output_padding attribute.
Here is my code:

```py
my_input = tensor([[[ 1.42e+00,  2.63e+00,  1.38e+00,  8.38e-01, -2.40e-01,  3.47e-01,
           9.39e-01, -1.70e+00,  9.41e-01],
         [ 1.48e+00,  1.59e+00,  8.10e-01, -5.31e-01, -3.23e+00,  3.47e+00,
           5.13e+00,  8.14e+00,  1.18e+00],
         [ 6.23e-01,  4.88e+00,  3.44e+00, -2.56e+00, -2.04e+00,  4.17e+00,
          -3.82e+00,  1.94e-01,  2.85e-01],
         [ 2.13e+00,  3.15e-01, -4.79e-01,  1.69e+00,  1.51e+00, -2.41e+00,
           4.35e+00, -1.04e+00,  3.94e+00],
         [ 1.36e-01,  8.97e-02, -1.96e-01,  8.24e-02,  2.17e+00,  1.37e+00,
          -3.01e-01,  3.12e+00,  6.68e-01]],

        [[ 3.04e+00,  6.06e-01, -9.81e-01, -1.61e+00, -2.45e-02,  1.83e+00,
           1.65e+00,  5.01e+00,  1.51e+00],
         [-2.03e-01,  1.09e+00, -2.80e+00, -6.62e-01,  2.44e-01,  7.15e+00,
           1.63e+00,  7.22e-01, -2.20e+00],
         [ 3.40e+00,  6.09e-01, -9.68e+00,  8.82e+00,  3.99e-03, -5.73e+00,
           9.31e+00,  3.73e+00,  1.90e+00],
         [-8.22e-01, -3.69e+00, -1.51e+00,  1.07e+01, -3.73e+00,  3.88e+00,
           2.16e+00, -2.46e+00,  3.51e+00],
         [-1.77e-01, -2.54e+00,  4.76e+00,  3.92e+00, -2.39e+00,  3.02e+00,
           5.19e+00, -1.17e+00,  7.10e-01]]], dtype=torch.float64)

my_weight = tensor([[[ 0.41,  0.10,  0.73,  0.21, -0.35, -0.35, -1.60],
         [ 0.27,  0.58,  0.30, -0.14,  0.04,  0.33,  1.88],
         [ 0.95,  1.99, -2.01, -0.02,  0.59, -1.88, -1.05]],

        [[ 0.87,  0.19, -0.96, -0.22,  0.31,  0.15,  0.02],
         [-0.28,  0.91, -1.56,  0.13,  0.48,  2.22, -0.81],
         [ 1.03,  1.01, -0.97,  0.80, -0.19, -2.13,  1.62]]],
       dtype=torch.float64)

my_bias = tensor([-1.94, -0.15], dtype=torch.float64)

torch.nn.functional.conv2d(input=my_input, weight=my_weight, bias=my_bias, stride=[1], padding=[0], dilation=[1])
```

The last line returns this:

`RuntimeError: expected output_padding to be a single integer value or a list of 1 values to match the convolution dimensions, but got output_padding=[0, 0]`

The issue is that conv2d does NOT have an attribute output_padding, and if I try to add it, like this:
`torch.nn.functional.conv2d(input=my_input, weight=my_weight, bias=my_bias, stride=[1], padding=[0], dilation=[1], output_padding=[0])`

I get this error:

```
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
      didn't match because some of the keywords were incorrect: output_padding
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, str padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)
      didn't match because some of the keywords were incorrect: output_padding
```

This clearly shows, that there is an error in the conv2d() program. Can someone that is a bit more knowledgeable in pytorch confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your specific error, but your tensors are the wrong shape for the `conv2d` function.

From the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.conv2d.html), `conv2d` expects the following tensor shapes:

- `input` - `(batch_size, in_channels, i*H, i*W)`
- `weight` - `(out_channels, in_channels / groups, k*H, k*W)`
- `bias` - None or `(out_channels)`
- `stride` - integer or tuple of shape `(s*H, s*W)`
- `padding` - string value, number, or tuple of shape `(pad*H, pad*W)`
- `dilation` - integer or tuple `(d*H, d*W)`
- `groups` - integer

Your tensors have the shape:

- `input` - `(2, 5, 9)` (missing a dimension)
- `weight` - `(2, 3, 7)` (missing a dimension
- `bias` - `(2,)` (correct number of dimensions)
- `stride` - `[1]` - should be an integer or a tuple of two values
- `padding` - `[0]` - should be a string, integer or tuple of two values
- `dilation` - `[1]` - should be a integer or a tuple of two values

`conv2d` work as expected when the correct tensor shapes are passed

```py
batch_size = 2
in_channels = 8
out_channels = 16
input_size = 32
kernel_size = 3
stride = 1 # or (1, 1)
padding = 0 # or (0, 0)
dilation = 1 # (1, 1)

torch.nn.functional.conv2d(
        input=torch.randn(batch_size, in_channels, input_size, input_size), 
        weight=torch.randn(out_channels, in_channels, kernel_size, kernel_size), 
        bias=torch.randn(out_channels),
        stride=stride, 
        padding=padding, 
        dilation=dilation
                        )
```

The error message comes from [shape_inference.cpp](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/d0627cc2af41dbfccf4d74b8ef9fcebc2a89bb78/torch/csrc/lazy/core/shape_inference.cpp#L85). My guess is the incorrect input shapes are causing something to be dispatched to the wrong shape checker.

Comment: Can I just add a 1 as the first dimension for the input and weight? (1, 2, 5, 9) (1, 2, 3, 7)

Comment: You need to read and understand the documentation for the function you are trying to use. The dimensions for the input and the weight do not mean the same thing. You can add a unit dimension to the input for a unit batch. However, the first dimension of the weight represents the number of output channels for the convolution which has to match your bias shape.